# How to stop double tap in Skyrim Special Edition?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I got Skyrim for the Xbox One and right off the back I've been having inventory issues. For some reason it double action items but it only happens when in the inventory. For example, when I'm consuming items it will consume the potion of healing but also consume the poison that was under it. Or if I'm bartering it will sell the iron axe as well as the artifact under it. Literally anything that requires the inventory and it only happens about every seventh action. And its not my controller since i don't have this issue with other games.

How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: Is this console or PC? Perhaps a button or function is stuck.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf "I got Skyrim for the Xbox One"

Comment: _"And its not my controller since i don't have this issue with other games"_ Other games might not register double clicks as fast as Skyrim does. A better test would be to check if Skyrim shows the same problem when you use a different controller (or even just a different **button** on the same controller, if you can reassign controls, not sure about that)

Answer (score 3):

I know you mentioned that the controller works for other games just fine, but hear me out when I say you should try disconnecting and reconnecting the controller. There's a possibility the games software isn't reading the controller correctly and re-establishing a connection might fix it. However, if that doesn't, follow the process below.

### Restart Skyrim

- Go the Xbox One home screen and close the application and restart it

### Power Cycle your console

1. Press and hold the [Xbox] button on the front of the console for 10 seconds.
2. Unplug the console's power cable and wait for 10 seconds.
3. Plug the power cable back in and turn the console back on by pressing the [Xbox] button again.

NOTE: People have posted on other forums that the power cycle fixed the issue. If this doesn't fix your issue keep following along.

### Disable Mods

1. To disable mods, select **Mods** from the **Main Menu.**
2. Select the mod you want to disable, select it and use the **Disable** option

### Delete your Mods

1. Select Mods from the **Main Menu**.
2. Find the Mod you want to delete from your Library, select it, and use the **Delete** option.

NOTE: If you are unable to load the game to delete your mods, you can still do so by following the below steps:

1. Navigate to **My Games and Apps** from the Xbox One dashboard.
2. Highlight Skyrim from the Games category.
3. Press [Menu] on your controller and select **Manage Game**.
4. Navigate to the right where the Saved Data is located and highlight **Reserved Space**.
5. Press [Menu] on your controller and select **Clear reserved space**.

NOTE: If the reserved space fails to clear, you should power cycle your Xbox One and try again.

### Uninstall and Reinstall the Game

**DO NOT DELETE YOUR SAVE DATA**, only [uninstall and reinstall the game.](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/troubleshooting/free-up-hard-drive-space) If none of this helped get in touch with [Xbox Support](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/contact-us) they'll be more than willing to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

**This appears to be a memory related issue**

After playing on the XBox One for more hours than I care to admit, this problem appears to be memory related.  Specifically, the more time is spent playing the more likely that this glitch occurs.

In my experience, the only fix that is needed is to close the game from the start menu.  That will clear the memory.  I have never seen it corrupt a save, so saving or quick saving, stopping the game, then immediately restarting has always fixed the problem.

I have not experienced any difference with this with or without mods, except that many mods cause a CTD which ends up, of course, clearing the memory.  As such, I've found that any mods that cause consistent crashes tends to prevent this, but only coincidentally.

On the other hand, purposefully causing this is disturbingly easy.  I've found that switching to other applications while Skyrim is "running" (e.g. save, but don't quit the game, then switch to, say Netflix, then come back) tends to significantly increase the odds of this "stuttering" effect.

One note, while the above says that it only affects the sales, that's not quite correct.  It's most notable in the sales menus, however, it tends to cause "stuttering" while moving and in combat, though the effect isn't as obvious (or as annoying.)